# Grails Spring Security forcing user to a specific screen after successful authentication

Tags: authentication, grails, groovy, spring-security

Here is the scenario. I have two objects `Users` (with username/password) and `UserInfo` with rest of the data related to user. The `Users` is an old table with thousands of records and `UserInfo` is fairly new. I want to get as much `UserInfo` as I can when the user first logs in.

I'd like to force user to a custom screen after first login and ask for the `UserInfo` data. Once I get the "required" data in the new screen, I dont show it till the user voluntarily wants to fill in the data under "Profile".

Since there are multiple entry points to the application, I dont want to update all the controllers to check for this.

Is there a way I can use a `Spring Security filter` or something which is executed on successful login? I had a look at `ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>` but it doesnt solve the problem as if I copy paste the link in the browser, it lets me go ahead to the destination without asking for "extra information".

In a nutshell, I want a check after each login which, if fails, user is not allowed to enter the application. No matter how he tries to get in.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this with a regular Grails filter, described here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters

Answer (score 1):

In your `Config.groovy`, configure Spring Security's `defaultTargetUrl` and tell it to always redirect there:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/userInfo/edit'
```

In your `UserInfoController`'s edit action, you can check that the required fields are present (`userInfo.validate()` perhaps?) and if they are, redirect to wherever you like, perhaps '/', otherwise render the edit info view.

Comment: An advantage to this over a filter is that it will only be executed on login, as opposed to viewing any page.

Comment: Great approach @doelleri. However if the user tries to paste the URL, he can bypass this step right?

Comment: Ah... good point, I forgot once they are logged in they will be able to go to any page by URL manipulation. So yes, you would need a filter to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt what @doelleri proposed and enhance the rule by those steps:

1. run a batch task to assign a temporary ROLE_DISABLED role to each user who does not provide supplemental information yet. If the user already had some roles, save them in some property.
2. setup your authorization rule as that users with ROLE_DISABLED role only allowed to access /userInfo/edit.
3. in /userInfo/edit, if the user has a ROLE_DISABLED role, render the information input view, and resume user's role after it successfully updated its information. Otherwise redirect to '/' or the path it requested.